# How can I convert bytes available to bytes available in KB, MB, GB etc?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm calculating total bytes available in particular folder and I want to convert the total bytes available to total bytes available in KB, MB, GB etc.

Is there any inbuilt function available in c# which I can use?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a very Informative Blog Regarding this :

https://askgif.com/blog/143/how-to-convert-given-bytes-in-kb-mb-gb-etc/ (Courtesy: https://askgif.com/)

if you are calculating total bytes then you can use the following function to find out the respective total bytes in KB, MB, GB, TB etc.

```
static String BytesToString(long byteCount)
    {
        string[] suf = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" }; //Longs run out around EB
        if (byteCount == 0)
            return "0" + suf[0];
        long bytes = Math.Abs(byteCount);
        int place = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, 1024)));
        double num = Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(1024, place), 1);
        return (Math.Sign(byteCount) * num).ToString() + suf[place];
    }
```

Hope this will help you.